# Angular: get service data in child component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 component which acts as the base component for pulling page data from the server. This component may set certain values that are common to all page components that use it.

I have a page component that has a very specific node it needs to pull from the data (in the example "leadText"). What is the simplest way to do this without making the base component look for this value?

Here is the sample code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-base-page',
    templateUrl: './base-page.component.html'
})
export class BasePageComponent implements OnInit {

    page: string;
    data: any[] = [];
    errorMessage: string;
    header: string;

    constructor(
        public getPageService: GetPageService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPage();
    }

    /* Handle the getPageService observable */
    getPage() {
        this.getPageService.getPage(this.page)
            .subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    this.data = data;
                    this.header = data.header;
                },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );

    }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    template: '<div [innerHTML]="leadText"></div>'
})
export class AboutPageComponent extends BasePageComponent {
    page: string = 'about';
    leadText: string;
    // how to get string data.leadText from parent component?
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Subjects here that your derived component can subscribe to:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
...
data$ = new Subject();
...
getPage() {
    this.getPageService.getPage(this.page)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.data$.next(data); // pass value in here
                this.header = data.header;
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

}
```

derived component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    template: '<div [innerHTML]="leadText | async"></div>'
})
export class AboutPageComponent extends BasePageComponent {
    page: string = 'about';
    // note that your data is now an observable and must be treated asynchronously
    leadText = this.data$.map((data: any) => data.leadText)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**One way:** 
If you are using your `AboutPageComponent` in your `base-page.component.html` like this:

```
<h1>Base Page Component</h1>
<app-about></app-about>
```

You can use `leadText` as input parameter of your Component like following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    template: '<div [innerHTML]="leadText"></div>'
})
export class AboutPageComponent extends BasePageComponent {
    page: string = 'about';

    @Input() leadText: string;
}
```

and in your `base-page.component.html`:

```
<h1>Base Page Component</h1>
<app-about [leadText]="data.leadText"></app-about>
```

**Second way:**
You could use a service, where you cache the respective data.

```
@Injectable()
export service CacheService {

    leadText: string;

    constructor(){}

    setLeadText(leadText: string) {this.leadText = leadText;}
    getLeadText(){return this.leadText;}
}
```

And you would call the setter in your subscription:

```
.subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
         this.data = data;
         this.header = data.header;
         this.cacheService.setLeadText(data.leadText); //Service call to set the leadText value
        },
         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    )
```

You could also move your request in a service method, where you set the respective leadText value.

And in your `AboutPageComponent` you would do something like this:

```
export class AboutPageComponent extends BasePageComponent {
    page: string = 'about';
    leadText: string;

    constructor(private cacheService: CacheService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.leadText = this.cacheService.getLeadText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the AboutPageComponent is not being used within the base-page-component.html.

Comment: So i have added another method to my answer. I hope this will help =)